# Check for empty row from mysql in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, isset, isnullorempty

I am trying to get a set of id from one table and get the details of the id from another table. Both tables are from 2 different database on two separate servers. I get an error when the data in the other table is empty.

In this example below, I stored all the user_id in an array called $user_data. Then, I would like to append to the existing array and add more info like first_name, last_name and email to the same user_id.

table: user

```
$user_data = array();

$sql_get_userid = "SELECT user_id FROM user
                   WHERE apply_date = ?";

$statement_get_id = $DB_3306->link->prepare($sql_get_userid);
$statement_get_id->bind_param("s", $date);
$statement_get_id->execute();

if($rs_get_id =  $statement_get_id->get_result())
{
    while($row = $rs_get_id->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $user_data[] = $row;
    }
}
```

There are times when the user_id might still exist but the data associated with the user_id in the other table is obsolete and deleted. Therefore, I get an error when I try to retrieve the non-existing data.

table: user_personal

```
$sql_get_user_data = "SELECT first_name, last_name, email FROM user_personal
WHERE user_id = ?"

foreach($user_id as $user => $child)
{ 
    $user_id = $child['user_id'];

    $statement_get_data = $DB_3308->link->prepare($sql_get_user_data);
    $statement_get_data->bind_param("s", $user_id);
    $statement_get_data->execute();

    if($rs_get_data = $statement_get_data->get_result())
    {
        while($row = $rs_get_data ->fetch_assoc())
        {
            if(isset($row['first_name']) && !empty($row['first_name']))
            {
               $first_name = $row['first_name'];
            }
            else
            {
                $first_name = 'NA';
            }
            $user_data[$user]['first_name'] = $first_name;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see from the second part of the code, I try to check if the data is set and not empty and to add a message if it's empty. I still get an error "Notice: Undefined index". What did I do wrong here?

EDIT:
Actually the $user_data doesn't even append the data if the other table doesn't have it.

```
//A rough idea of the data stored in $user_data
$user_data = Array( [0] => Array ( [user_id] => 111), [1] => Array ( [user_id] => 222) [2] => Array ( [user_id] => 333))

//If user_id = 333 has no data associated with it in user_personal table the array would look like this (showing only first_name value)
 $user_data = Array( [0] => Array ( [user_id] => 111 [first_name] => Kenny ), [1] => Array ( [user_id] => 222 [first_name] => Kenny) [2] => Array ( [user_id] => 333))
```

Actually the array from the codes here are called to an display file where the data are displayed. So, I moved the if(isset(var) && !empty(var)) to that file and so far it works fine.

Comment: can you tell the line at which notice:" undefined index" is coming?

Comment: Hey! The statement should be prepared only once! Move your `$statement_get_data = $DB_3308->link->prepare($sql_get_user_data);` outside the `foreach` loop.

Comment: @stackMonk - it's on another php file where I output the result. If I have 7 user_id and only 6 have data, the last one with no data will give me an error. The other 6 will echo with no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code from

```
        if(isset($row['first_name']) && !empty($row['first_name']))
        {
           $first_name = $row['first_name'];
        }
        else
        {
            $first_name = 'NA';
        }

     to 

        if($row['first_name']!='')
        {
           $first_name = $row['first_name'];
        }
        else
        {
            $first_name = 'NA';
        }
```

isset will never work because  `$row['first_name']` always set

Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: Actually Sohail, I tried isset($row['first_name']) && !empty($row['first_name']) && ($row['first_name']) != "" ... but it gives me same error.

Comment: to debug your variable what you have in it use var_dump($row['first_name']);

Answer (score 0):

please change the code in second code block which is this

```
$statement_get_data->bind_param("is", $user_id);
```

because amount of parameter needed is only one and supplied two 
two types 
i for integer and 
s for string

so change that line to

```
$statement_get_data->bind_param("i", $user_id);
```

please see the php menual about bind_param

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Actually that was a typo on my end. It still doesn't work after changing the param.